# Why does instanciating a Transform class creates a new GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, instantiation

So I was following a tutorial and noticed that the person used Transform to instantiate a new gameObject from a prefab:

```
private List<Transform> segments = new List<Transform>();
//segment prefab is a prefab added from the unity editor
public Transform segmentPrefab;

public void Grow()
{
    Transform segment = Instantiate(segmentPrefab);
    segment.position = segments[segments.Count - 1].position;
    segments.Add(segment);
}
```

And after calling Grow from another function, a new GameObject that uses the `segmentPrefab` prefab is instantiated and appeared on the screen.

I am aware of the fact that this person used generic method of instantiate, but I am confused about why instantiating `Transform` creates a new `GameObject`. I thought `Transform` class only serves as a property of `GameObject`, not a complete object. Do I have some misunderstanding of `GameObjects` in unity?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html): *"If you are cloning a Component the GameObject it is attached to is also cloned, again with an optional position and rotation."*. And `Transform` is a `Component`

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you very much! I didn't notice this line in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`Object.Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

> If you are cloning a Component the GameObject it is attached to is also cloned, again with an optional position and rotation.
>
> When you clone a GameObject or Component, all child objects and components are also cloned with their properties set like those of the original object.

And [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) **is** a [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html).

In simple words:

Because it wouldn't make any sense at all to create an instance of a `Component` without that `Component` being attached to any `GameObject`.

-> What exactly would you do with only a `Transform` (or any other `Component`) that isn't attached to anything? ;)

That's also the reason why `new` is forbidden on any class deriving from `Component` as they need to be created by the underlying c++ engine and be connected to a `GameObject`.

Have in mind that the entire Unity engine is actually in `c++`. Whatever you do in `c#` is just an API layer on top of that `c++` engine core to make it easier to use for us developers